My puppy keeps bullying our new dog guest
I been having an issue with my 1 year old puppy named Leia. She is a rottweiler/french bulldog mix named Leia and a ball of energy. The problem occurred when we took in my wife’s childhood dog to babysit her while her parents are on vacation. She is a small, 14-year-old maltese/poodle mix named Lulu and when we try to sleep at night (we all sleep in the same bed), Leia will follow and stare at Lulu for HOURS. Just nonstop, we were up till 4am last night until she finally gave up but I have no idea how to train this out of her. We try to make sure she respects Lulu’s boundaries during the day with some training, but at bedtime she just insists on following and sniffing her. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You write that Leia "stares at Lulu for hours", but also that she " insists on following and sniffing her.". Those are 2 different behaviors that may have different solutions. Please [edit] your question and describe the problematic behavior in more detail. Also the arrangement in the bedroom: do both dogs sleep in your bed or in separate dog beds or a different configuration?
